# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning, readfile, writefile, async

Tags: javascript, node.js

my code is not working and i get the following error:

```
TypeError: inventors.push is not a function
    at file:///C:/Users/tomma/OneDrive/Bureaublad/taller%20de%20programacion%202/javascriptFiles/TP2-2C-c/async/ejercicioPromesas.js:10:19        
(node:9536) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: inventors is not defined
    at file:///C:/Users/tomma/OneDrive/Bureaublad/taller%20de%20programacion%202/javascriptFiles/TP2-2C-c/async/ejercicioPromesas.js:15:46        
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:9536) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, 
use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9536) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

code:

```
import fs from 'fs/promises'
const path = './inventors.json';

const inventor = {first: 'Rene', last: ' Favarolo', year: 1923};

fs.readFile(path, 'utf-8').then(data =>{
   
        const inventors = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(inventors);
        await inventors.push(inventor);
    return fs.writeFile (path,JSON.stringify(inventors, null, ' '))
}).then( () => ( 
    console.log('Archivo actualizado')
)
);
```

Please help me

Comment: `await` in a non-async function isn't allowed.

Comment: It seems that stored data in file is not an array. So after you parse it you wont get a valid js array so you can't push something in it.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the Try Catch statement.

```
import fs from 'fs/promises' const path = './inventors.json';

const inventor = {first: 'Rene', last: ' Favarolo', year: 1923};

fs.readFile(path, 'utf-8').then(async(data) =>{
    try{
       const inventors = JSON.parse(data);
       console.log(inventors);
       await inventors.push(inventor);
    }
    catch(err){
       
    }
}
    
return fs.writeFile (path,JSON.stringify(inventors, null, ' '))
}).then( () => ( console.log('Archivo actualizado') ) );
```